# Salary Negotiation for Remote Work Opportunity

Tags: negotiation

I wanted some tips on salary negotiation for a remote work opportunity at a big company. Initially this job opening was available in the Silicon Valley and the company was looking for someone who can work in their headquarters office in Silicon Valley in US.

However, when I applied for this job from UK as a remote work opportunity, the employer showed interest and they found my prior experience and resume interesting.

I would like to know if I can negotiate the salary with the employer considering the salary which is offered for the same role in US? Or will they apply the Industry Standard for salary in UK while negotiating?

Answer (score 5):

Being in a similar situation I would like to think that a compromise in the middle to be the most likely scenario:

The company gives up having you in office but gets a lower cost.

You get flexibility and some salary more than the UK standard.

A win-win situation for both.

That being said I do know of people working remotely that get the same full salary as they would have if working onsite for that company so it's entirely possible and others that adjust their salaries based on where their (remote) staff is based and relevant cost of living.

Comment: @NeonFlash you re welcome, given that I am a relatively new entry to the working place, leave the post open without checking an 'accepted answer' for 24h or so so other people perhaps with more experience than me can chime in on this!